# NSOperation Queue Priority Does Not Work As Expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperation

I'm studying the `NSOperation` class and tried to simulate a situation, when I need to manage the priority of an operation.

Please consider the following code:

```
@implementation MyOperation // First custom NSOperation class


- (void)main {

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSLog(@"First operation start"); 
    }
}

@implementation MySecondOperation // Second custom NSOperation class

- (void)main {

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSLog(@"Second operation start");
    }
}

@implementation ViewController // Other class using NSOperations

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSOperationQueue *myQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];

    MyOperation *firstOperation = [MyOperation new];

    MySecondOperation *secondOperation = [MySecondOperation new];

    [firstOperation setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityLow];
    [secondOperation setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityHigh];

    [myQueue addOperation:secondOperation];
    [myQueue addOperation:firstOperation];

}
```

Code is pretty straightforward. However, you will be surprised to see output:

```
2015-08-12 20:32:09.433 NSOperationTesting[1181:39809] First operation start
2015-08-12 20:32:09.433 NSOperationTesting[1181:39811] Second operation start
```

NSOperation with lower priority start before operation, with higher. I know, NSOperationQueue work in FIFO order, but, i specifically set priority of both operations, so why first operation complete first? It suppose to be after second (with higher priority).

Comment: The operations are running concurrently, so you have a race condition with absolutely no assurances of which will hit their respective `NSLog` statement first. As the documentation says "You should use priority values only as needed to classify the relative priority of non-dependent operations. Priority values should not be used to implement dependency management among different operation objects. If you need to establish dependencies between operations, use the `addDependency:` method instead."

Comment: Or set the maxConcurrency to 1. Or use a serial queue in GCD

Comment: he didn't add them both at the same time with addOperations thats probably why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use or depend on `QueuePriority` to set a specific order in which your `operations` should be executed because you will not have any guarantees that your operations will execute by priority order.

Per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSOperation/queuePriority):

> You should use priority values only as needed to classify the relative
>   priority of non-dependent operations. Priority values should not be
>   used to implement dependency management among different operation
>   objects. If you need to establish dependencies between operations, use
>   the `addDependency:` method instead.

If you need to execute your operations in a specific order because one of them is dependent on the other you should use the `addDependency:` method of `NSOperation`.
So you should do something like this:

```
[firstOperation addDependency: secondOperation];
```

This will guarantee that `firstOperation` will execute after `secondOperation`.

Comment: i understand about dependencies. But, can you answer simple question - in my example, highest priority operation executre first or we cant actualyl find out?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Priorities help to order the operations execution order within the queue by promoting high priority operations over low priority ones from the currently ready operations. In your specific case, if the operation with Low priority is ready before the one with High priority, the Low priority operation will be executed first. If you want to prevent the Low priority operation to execute before the High priority operation you should make it dependent on the High priority operation instead of setting their priority.

Comment: operationPriority is used when OperationQueue selects next operation to execute. If operation is started priority means nothing. So when you add first operation it will start execution regardless to it's priority. You can extend your example and add lots of operations with different priorities and you will see the difference.

Comment: The documentation says: "Operation.QueuePriority
These constants let you prioritize the order in which operations execute" 
And you say "You should not use or depend on QueuePriority to set a specific order in which your operations should be executed"
I don't understand

Answer (score 4):

Try setting myQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1.  My guess is that it is running your operations concurrently.

Answer (score 4):

Do not trust `NSLog`. You only added two operations and they were executed at the same time concurrently. I have modified and ran your code and the following example shows that the high priority operations are executed before the lower priority ones.

```
NSOperationQueue *myQueue  = [NSOperationQueue new];
NSMutableArray *operations = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    MyOperation *firstOperation = [MyOperation new];

    MySecondOperation *secondOperation = [MySecondOperation new];

    [firstOperation setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityLow];
    [secondOperation setQueuePriority:NSOperationQueuePriorityHigh];

    [operatons addObject:firstOperation];
    [operatons addObject:secondOperation];
}

[myQueue addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

Output:

```
2015-08-12 19:47:30.826 oper[1137:31464] Second operation start
2015-08-12 19:47:30.826 oper[1137:31487] Second operation start
2015-08-12 19:47:30.826 oper[1137:31465] Second operation start
...
2015-08-12 19:47:36.443 oper[1137:31491] First operation start
2015-08-12 19:47:36.443 oper[1137:31491] First operation start
2015-08-12 19:47:36.443 oper[1137:31491] First operation start
```

Edit:
As Rob stated, `NSOperation` priorities do not guarantee the order of execution. If you want to wait until an operation is finished before you start another one, use `addDependency:` method.

Comment: its nice, that your example work. But still, it look odd for me, that NSOperationQueue consider to execute lower priority task first..

Comment: It was not executed first. In your example, both operations were executed at the same time, according to NSLog (20:32:09.433). NSLog does not guarantee that the output will be 100% chronological.

Comment: This code only happens to work because you added 20,000 operations. If you reduce your loop from 10,000 to something like 3 (where all six operations may run concurrently), you start to see the same behavior as the OP.

Comment: @Rob You already said that there is a race condition here. When you add 6 operations you can't really measure anything because most likely they will be moved to 6 threads and executed at the same time. This is how NSOperationQueue works.

Comment: That's my point. I thought you claimed that your example that "shows that the high priority operations are executed before the lower priority ones." My point is that this is _not_ the case. It's merely that it will prioritize the _starting_ of high priority operations before low priority ones, but not that they'll actually _execute_ (much less finish) in that order. The problem is not that he shouldn't trust `NSLog`, but merely that in a concurrent environment he shouldn't conflate the starting of the operation with its execution or completion.

Comment: No, I was not claiming that. I have edited my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the property `operation.qualityOfService` was giving me much better results as compared to `operation.queuePriority`. You might want to give it a try.

I used `operation.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceUserInteractive` for high priority operations and `operation.qualityOfService = NSQualityOfServiceDefault` for normal priority operations and it worked as expected.

You can use below code to test this out.

```
#define kMaxSeconds 5
#define kSleepTime 1

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger currentCount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSOperationQueue* operationQueue;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.currentCount = 0;

    [self addOperationInQueueWithQuality:NSQualityOfServiceUserInteractive];
    [self addOperationInQueueWithQuality:NSQualityOfServiceDefault];
    [self addOperationInQueueWithQuality:NSQualityOfServiceUserInteractive];
    [self addOperationInQueueWithQuality:NSQualityOfServiceDefault];
    [self addOperationInQueueWithQuality:NSQualityOfServiceUserInteractive];
}

- (void)addOperationInQueueWithQuality:(NSQualityOfService)quality{
    if(!self.operationQueue){
        self.operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    }
    self.currentCount++;
    NSInteger blockNumber = self.currentCount;
    NSBlockOperation* blockOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        for(int i=0; i < kMaxSeconds; i++){
            NSMutableString* str = [NSMutableString new];
            for(int j = 0; j < self.currentCount+1; j++){
                if(j == blockNumber){
                    [str appendString:@"    |"];
                }else{
                    [str appendString:@"    ."];
                }
            }
            NSLog(@"%@", [str copy]);
            sleep(kSleepTime);
        }
    }];
    blockOperation.qualityOfService = quality;
    blockOperation.completionBlock = ^{
        NSLog(@"Block operation %ld completed", blockNumber);
    };
    [self.operationQueue addOperation:blockOperation];
}

@end
```